# change connection string password externally

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

ASP.NET websites should store connection string in web.config file for various reasons and best practice. Today I was asked by my manager that "Can we store DB username and password in another location on top of web.config file? It will be easier to change SQL id/password without having developer change it every time on Production if that is done".

I wanted to ask experts the same question - is it possible to retrieve SQL connection string id/password from another place instead of web.config? I know the best practice is to store it into web.config but I am just curious is it even possible at all?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can read the username/password from virtually anything that is accessible through code (if I understand your question correctly).

**Have you looked at [Web Config Transformations](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-web-config-file-transformations-3-of-12)?**

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will go thru it. Basically they want to be able to change SQL id/password more frequently and externally without the need of developer once the setup is done.

Comment: Well unless you know a specific location where they'd like to change these values I would say the web.config is the way to go. It only requires access to the filesystem where the website is hosted and the application doesn't need to be re-deployed nor does it need a developer to do it.